# jQuery outerWidth working as setter -- is this reliable

Tags: jquery

The current jQuery documentation makes no mention of .outerWidth() behaving as a setter.  While I am sure I could work it out, setting the width of an element in a line based on the calculated widths of other elements in the line is cumbersome and doesn't work equally in IE9 when compared to the other major browsers.  On a hunch, I tried using .outerWidth() as a setter.  It works beautifully and equally in all browsers.

Here is the line of code (with the "value" set using a JavaScript variable, whose value is confirmed by an alert):

```
$("#WelcomeMessage").outerWidth(WidthAvailableForWelcomeMessage);
```

And here are the jQuery references in my site:

```
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

One comment in the documentation of .outWidth(), at the end of the comments section, says that this feature is in the jQuery ui.  Commenting out the ref to the ui makes it not work.  But I can't find explicit documentation concerning this feature anywhere.

Is this behavior reliable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>The documentation for jQuery ui has always been spotty at best, and I too can't find any documentation on it. I would suggest not using `outerWidth` as a setter and finding an alternative.</strike>

`outerWidth` is going to be a setter and a getter in jquery 1.8, it is safe to use it as long as you continue to include jQuery ui in your code until you upgrade to jquery 1.8

http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/22/jquery-1-8-beta-1-see-whats-coming-and-going/

at least, it is currently planned to be in 1.8. Since it is still beta, that could of course change.

Comment: What a shame. It works so beautifully!! I will mark this as the answer if, after a bit, no one else weighs in with a ref that makes it a setter that can be relied upon now and in the future.

Comment: I believe it is a helper method being used internally by jQuery UI widgets. If that is the case, it is not safe to use at this point.

Comment: If you want a more definitive answer, post the question on the jQuery UI forums. I'm sure one of the jQuery UI developers will respond. http://forum.jquery.com

Comment: I read the source and they indeed overwrite jQuery's `outerWidth`... extremely bad practice to do that if they don't mean it as public? But yea answer from the guys themselves is probably better.

Comment: @Esailija It is also still present in the 1.9pre code source, so if anything you can be almost sure that it will still be available in 1.9

Comment: Refer to forum on using jQuery ui as suggested by Kevin B if further information is desired.  I will proceed using it as a setter, since development of the server side is months away and I can monitor jQuery 1.8 development.